# How to draw D3 Map with United States, Canada, Mexico and Puerto Rico

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js

I'm looking to use D3 to draw a map with some points on it. The Albers Projection US works great. I need a map with Canada (by province), Mexico (by state) and Puerto Rico on it as well. Any recommendation for the best projection on this map would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!-Dre

Answer (score 13):

As far as projections go, the [azimuthal equidistant projection](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3757110) isn’t a bad choice for this purpose:

[image: azimuthal-equidistant]

You should be able to follow my [Let’s Make a Map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) tutorial to get the province and state-level data, or you can use the [World Atlas project](https://github.com/mbostock/world-atlas) for the same, using the [Admin 1 dataset](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/) from Natural Earth.

Comment: Mike,
Thanks! Your link is extremely helpful. I don't have enough rep to vote you up yet (I've been a massive lurker of Stack Overflow and yours for a while now though)

Sorry for the delay on response.